# Send messages to android devices using GCM asynchronously

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging

I have a java based app server from which I want to send notifications to android devices. I was thinking of using this lib: https://github.com/google/gcm for sending notifications. But it does not seem to support async send. Is there any existing library using which I can send notifications asynchronously to the android devices.

Comment: I have not run any app asynchronously, however, in [Choosing a GCM Connection Server Protocol](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server), IMO, you can find more info about `XMPP (CCS): Asynchronous`

Comment: @BNK yeah I saw this. But wanted to check if there are any ready to use libraries in java for this.

Comment: Were you ever able to find anything on this topic? I have the same issue.